# Changing Python /user/.cache folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, environment-variables, temp

When I install and run natural language processing modules from like huggingspace, they often download large machine learning modules into:
`C:\Users\User\.cache` directories or similar directories on the `C:\` drive in Windows.

My `C:` drive is a SSD with limited space, I keep on running out of space on it.

I would like to change the python `.cache` folder environment variable to a folder of my choice, as i use a development disk drive that is spacious and i got especially for this use case.

I could not find any way to change these directories, does anyone know how we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Cache directory

The default cache directory is `~/.cache/huggingface/datasets`. Change the cache location by setting the shell environment variable, `HF_DATASETS_CACHE` to another directory:

```
$export HF_DATASETS_CACHE="/path/to/another/directory"
```

When you load a dataset, you also have the option to change where the data is cached. Change the `cache_dir` parameter to the path you want:

```
>>> from datasets import load_dataset
>>> dataset = load_dataset('LOADING_SCRIPT', cache_dir="PATH/TO/MY/CACHE/DIR")
```

Similarly, you can change where a metric is cached with the `cache_dir` parameter:

```
>>> from datasets import load_metrit
>>> metric = load_metric('glue', 'mrpc', cache_dir="MY/CACHE/DIRECTORY")
```

from: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/cache